# Consuming .NET Web Service in Objective-C [iPhone]

Tags: .net, iphone, objective-c, web-services

I am looking for some tutorials on how I can consume a .Net webservice on the iPhone platform (3.0). I have never looked at Cocoa XML prasing before, to the more indepth the tutorial is the better.

We have an existing webservice framework currently in place, which return XML, so I would ideally like to consume these, as opposed to reimplimenting them to use JSON.

Thank you for taking the time to read this request.

Regards

Comment: Ok I found this link which seems very informative http://grabalife.com/2009/10/19/using-net-web-services-and-dataset-objects-in-your-iphone-app/ - not in front of a MAC at the moment so cant test it out, any other feedback would still be great though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, consuming a SOAP web service in a mobile environment can be pretty expensive.  I would highly recommend considering either a JSON or very simplified REST based XML service when delivering data to your iPhone application.